# boost::asio::async_read() of stream_descriptor now returning EOF

Tags: ubuntu, c++11, boost-asio, eof

Upgraded Ubuntu today from 14.10 to 15.04.  Now seeing different behaviour either in `boost::asio::async_read()`, `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor`, or tap/tun interfaces.  Calling `async_read()` immediately returns `boost::asio::error::eof`.  If I ignore the error and loop back up to start a new `async_read()` it does eventually read when bytes are available, and the application continues to work.

The problem with doing this workaround loop is the application now consumes 100% of a core as it sits in a tight loop continuously restarting the call to `async_read()`.

This is how I'm setting things up:

```
fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
....
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor my_stream( io_service);
my_stream.assign(fd, ec);
...
boost::asio::async_read(my_stream, my_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(16),
    [=](const EC &error, std::size_t bytes_read)
    {
        if (error) // <- this triggers with EOF error
```

Anyone know what may have changed in the newer kernels (tun/tap), or boost 1.55, to cause this end-of-file error when doing asynchronous reads?

Comment: did your network configuration change?

Comment: All I did was upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04.  As soon as I rebooted after the upgrade, I immediately noticed the change in behaviour because on the 3 computers where this code is running the logging of a message in the `if(error)` caused the log file to balloon.

Comment: Well. Did you network configuration change? (Can you verify that the tun/tap devices are actually present and operating, just for starters?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu 15.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Linux_kernel_3.19) contains the 3.19 kernel, which has a reported [regression](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96381) in the TUN/TAP user API:

> With kernel 3.19, a `read()` from a TUN/TAP file descriptor in non-blocking mode will return `0` when no data is available, rather than fail with `EAGAIN`.

Per the documentation, the return value from [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvmsg.html) should only be `0` when no message has been read and the the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.  Hence, the Boost.Asio [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L836-L844) treats a return of `0` as an indication that the peer has shutdown, and completes the `async_read()` operation with an error code of `boost::asio::error::eof`:

```cpp
// Read some data.
signed_size_type bytes = socket_ops::recv(s, bufs, count, flags, ec);

// Check for end of stream.
if (is_stream && bytes == 0)
{
  ec = boost::asio::error::eof;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I have not seen any reported regressions against either the event demultiplexer or `ioctl()`, so one stopgap may be to use [reactor style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) operations to know when data is available, then check size with [`posix::basic_stream_descriptor::bytes_readable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__basic_stream_descriptor/bytes_readable.html) and issue a synchronous `read()` operation for the exact amount of bytes.  This should prevent attempting to read when no data is available.

Comment: Many thanks for the link to the regression.  I would have spent a huge amount of time trying to figure out why this code was no longer working.