# boost::asio::async_read keeps returning eof on named pipe

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, named-pipes

Here is my sample code that opens a pipe in read mode. It uses `boost::asio` to read from the pipe. When data (let's say X bytes) is written to the pipe, it calls `on_read` with `ec=EOF`, `bytes=X` and X bytes of data in the buffer.

EOF is sent because the writer, after finishing writing to the pipe, closes it. I want to keep reading. That is why I call `pipe.async_wait()` in `on_read`. However, even if nothing is ready to be read from the pipe, `on_read` calls `my_pipe::async_read()` which again calls `on_read()` with `bytes = 0` and `ec=EOF`. This goes on in an infinite loop.

Why does it keeping reading `EOF` repeatedly?

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


class my_pipe final
{
public:
    explicit my_pipe(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);
    ~my_pipe();
private:
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor pipe;
    std::vector<char> _buf{};
    void async_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec);
    void on_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
};

my_pipe::my_pipe(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : pipe(io_service)
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/pipe1", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1)
        return;

    _buf.resize(8192);
    pipe.assign(fd);
    pipe.async_wait(boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read,
        boost::bind(&my_pipe::async_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

my_pipe::~my_pipe()
{
    pipe.close();
}

void my_pipe::async_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    std::cout << "async_read\n";
    if (ec)
        return;
    boost::asio::async_read(pipe, boost::asio::buffer(_buf),
        boost::bind(&my_pipe::on_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void my_pipe::on_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes)
{
    std::cout << "on_read. bytes=" << bytes << "\n";
    if (!ec || ec == boost::asio::error::eof) {
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::eof)
            std::cout << "eof\n";
        std::cout << "call async_read\n";
        pipe.async_wait(boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read,
            boost::bind(&my_pipe::async_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    } else {
        std::cout << "on_read error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    my_pipe obj(ios);
    ios.run();
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841168/boostasioasync-read-of-stream-descriptor-now-returning-eof

Comment: Why do you want to keep reading from a closed pipe? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @janm I intend to run this as a daemon which waits to read commands from the pipe. Other processes will send command through the pipe. I was expecting it to continue `async_wait` for `wait_read` after reading a command.
    I can always close and reopen the pipe every time a message is read but I was wondering if there was a way to clear the eof flag and continue waiting for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe is "widowed" when all handles on one end are closed.

In this case, after you get an EOF, you should close the pipe handle and then reopen the pipe. You can then issue an `async_read()` on the new descriptor to wait for more data.

If you have multiple writers, also consider that writes are only guaranteed to be atomic up to  `PIPE_BUF` bytes.